# Return a pointer from a function to an object initialized in main()

Tags: c++, pointers, object, struct, return

I have been struggling with this problem for a few hours now and I've searched for every term that made sense to me. I might even have already read through a relevant answer but didn't recognize it as such because I'm a little confused by pointers.

So, I have a struct that is part of an object which is part of a chain of objects that is "anchored" (if you can call it that) in another object, which is itself part of a chain which is "anchored" in an anchor object initialized in main.

```
struct values
{
    double val, ues;
}
class small
{
    public:
        values vals;
}
class big
{
    public:
        small *small_anchor;
}
values &getPointerToStruct(big *con)
{
    values *return_vals;
    if(con->small_anchor->vals.val==10)
        return_vals=con->small_anchor->vals;
    return (&return_vals);
}
int main()
{
    values *main_values=NULL;//This is supposed to be pointing to the "vals" struct contained inside the "small" object.
    big *big_anchor;
    big_anchor = new big;
    big_anchor->small_anchor = new small;
    big_anchor->small_anchor->vals.val=10;
    big_anchor->small_anchor->vals.ues=5;

    main_values = getPointerToStruct(&big_anchor);//now main_values should be pointing to the "vals" struct
    //I want to manipulate the value INSIDE the object itself
    main_values.val++;
}
```

I have tried every combination of `&`, `*` and no prefix I could come up with, but nothing would give the result I was hoping for. "Closest" I got was copying "vals" (from inside the object) into "main_values" so that I could manipulate the values there, which isn't of any use to me, as I want to manipulate the SOURCE of the variables.

Also please note that I left out the process of scrolling down the chains to get to the object I was trying to reach and that "return_vals" seems arbitrary, but it happens that there are two possible candidates that could be the struct my program is looking for and the "return_vals" contains the best candidate found so far and is overwritten when a better one is found, or returned when the routine ends.

Comment: Use `return *return_vals` _after_ you've actually instantiated an instance of `values` and assigned the pointer to `return_vals` otherwise you get UB.

Comment: "I have tried every combination of `&`, `*` " - you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
values &getPointerToStruct(big *con)
{
    values *return_vals;
    if(con->small_anchor->vals.val==10)
        return_vals=con->small_anchor->vals;
    return (&return_vals);
}
```

where I think you wanted

```
values *getPointerToStruct(big *con)
{
    values *return_vals = 0;
    if(con->small_anchor->vals.val==10)
        return_vals=&con->small_anchor->vals;
    return (return_vals);
}
```

But the `.` in     `main_values.val++;` is wrong anyway.  You need to be consistent about whether you wanted to work with a `values*` or a `values&`.  You could make all this work with a `values&` if you like, but then `main_values` should be a `values&` and not declared until you are ready to initialize it.  `return_vals` would not be practical as a `values&` because of the stated requirement that the full code gives it a tentative address that is conditionally modified later.  But even with `return_vals` as a `values*` you could still return a `values&` if that is what you preferred.

Comment: Totally did the trick. Also I appreciate the more advanced explanation you gave below your corrected example.